# I don't know how to solve $\int^{b}_{a} \sin x \times \ln(\cos x)\ dx$

Tags: integration

I don't know how to solve the question like this,can anybody help me?I think the method of "Integration by parts" can't solve this

$$\int^{b}_{a} \sin x \times \ln(\cos x)\ dx$$

Comment: Substitution: $u = \cos x$. The interval $[a,b]$ had better lie in the set where cosine is positive, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have sines and cosines together you can often try to use them to simplify things. since $\frac d{dx}\cos x\,=\,-\sin x$ you can set $u=\cos x$ to rewrite your integrand as 
$$\begin{align}
\int\ln u(-du) & = u - u\ln u\\
& = \cos x - \cos x\ln(\cos x)\bigg|_a^b\\
\end{align}$$ 
As pointed out in the comments, your interval $[a, b]$ better make the values of $\cos x$ positive otherwise we have a problem. (can you see why?)

Answer (score 1):

Set $$t=\cos(x)$$ then you will get $$dt=-\sin(x)dx$$ and our indefinite integral will be $$-\int\ln(t)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Perform the substitution $\cos x = t, dt = -sin(x) dx$

The integral becomes:

$$I = - \int_{\cos(a)}^{\cos(b)} ln(t)dt$$

which can be solved using integration by parts.

Comment: Personally, I enjoy using $\ln(t)=\int_1^t\frac1u\ du$ and interchanging integrals.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the change of variables suggested by others, the next step will be to integrate by parts. You can equally well start with the integration by parts. In case there is no problem with your limits (I skip them below), the calculation goes like this:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sin x\ln(\cos x)\,dx&=-\cos x\ln(\cos x)-\int(-\cos x)\frac{1}{\cos x}(-\sin x)\,dx\\
&=-\cos x\ln(\cos x)-\int\sin x\,dx\\
&=\cos x\bigl(1-\ln\cos x\bigr)+C.
\end{aligned}
$$